# How to open an url and save a file sent as response (excel) directly to google drive with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello and thanks for your time.

Below you will find a link (request) for the data/excel file that I would like to save directly to my google drive and in the future import to google sheets:

[https://digital.feprecisionplus.com/corppen/en-GB/cp-am/DownloadTool/GetPriceHistoryFile?modelString={%22GrsProjectId%22:%2236800083%22,%22ProjectName%22:%22corppen%22,%22ToolId%22:16,%22LanguageId%22:%221%22,%22LanguageCode%22:%22en-GB%22,%22OverrideDocumentCountryCode%22:null,%22forSaleIn%22:%22%22,%22FSIexclCT%22:%22%22}&filtersString={%22TypeCode%22:%22FA:N6SQ%22,%22FundName%22:%22JLR%20Bond%22,%22BaseCurrency%22:%22GBX%22,%22PriceType%22:1,%22TimePeriod%22:%22%22,%22StartDate%22:%22Mon%20Mar%2001%202021%22,%22EndDate%22:%22Thu%20Mar%2004%202021%22}](https://digital.feprecisionplus.com/corppen/en-GB/cp-am/DownloadTool/GetPriceHistoryFile?modelString=%7B%22GrsProjectId%22:%2236800083%22,%22ProjectName%22:%22corppen%22,%22ToolId%22:16,%22LanguageId%22:%221%22,%22LanguageCode%22:%22en-GB%22,%22OverrideDocumentCountryCode%22:null,%22forSaleIn%22:%22%22,%22FSIexclCT%22:%22%22%7D&filtersString=%7B%22TypeCode%22:%22FA:N6SQ%22,%22FundName%22:%22JLR%20Bond%22,%22BaseCurrency%22:%22GBX%22,%22PriceType%22:1,%22TimePeriod%22:%22%22,%22StartDate%22:%22Mon%20Mar%2001%202021%22,%22EndDate%22:%22Thu%20Mar%2004%202021%22%7D)

I tried google script below ( "my_URL" to be replaced with the link above)

```
function uploadFile() {    
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch("my_URL").getBlob()
    file = DriveApp.getFolderById("my_FolderID").createFile(blob);
}
```

but I am getting "Exception: Invalid argument: "my_URL"" response.

Would anyone be able to help me with getting that file saved to drive?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I tested your script using your URL, no error occurs. The XLSX file could be created. But from `but I am getting "Exception: Invalid argument: "my_URL"" response.`, I thought that you might have used `https://digital.feprecisionplus.com/corppen/en-GB/cp-am/DownloadTool/GetPriceHistoryFile?modelString={%22GrsProjectId%22:%2236800083%22,%22ProjectName%22:%22corppen%22,%22ToolId%22:16,%22LanguageId%22:%221%22,%22LanguageCode%22:%22en-GB%22,%22OverrideDocumentCountryCode%22:null,%22forSaleIn%22:%22%22,%22FSIexclCT%22:%22%22}&filtersString={%22TypeCode%22:%22FA:N6SQ%22,%22FundName%22:%22JLR%20Bond%22,%22BaseCurrency%22:%22GBX%22,%22PriceType%22:1,%22TimePeriod%22:%22%22,%22StartDate%22:%22Mon%20Mar%2001%202021%22,%22EndDate%22:%22Thu%20Mar%2004%202021%22}` as the URL. If it's so, such error occurs.
- In this case, please test the URL of `https://digital.feprecisionplus.com/corppen/en-GB/cp-am/DownloadTool/GetPriceHistoryFile?modelString=%7B%22GrsProjectId%22:%2236800083%22,%22ProjectName%22:%22corppen%22,%22ToolId%22:16,%22LanguageId%22:%221%22,%22LanguageCode%22:%22en-GB%22,%22OverrideDocumentCountryCode%22:null,%22forSaleIn%22:%22%22,%22FSIexclCT%22:%22%22%7D&filtersString=%7B%22TypeCode%22:%22FA:N6SQ%22,%22FundName%22:%22JLR%20Bond%22,%22BaseCurrency%22:%22GBX%22,%22PriceType%22:1,%22TimePeriod%22:%22%22,%22StartDate%22:%22Mon%20Mar%2001%202021%22,%22EndDate%22:%22Thu%20Mar%2004%202021%22%7D`.

  - `{` and `}` are encoded to `%7B` and `%7D`, respectively. (I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.)

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function uploadFile() {
  var url = "https://digital.feprecisionplus.com/corppen/en-GB/cp-am/DownloadTool/GetPriceHistoryFile?modelString=%7B%22GrsProjectId%22:%2236800083%22,%22ProjectName%22:%22corppen%22,%22ToolId%22:16,%22LanguageId%22:%221%22,%22LanguageCode%22:%22en-GB%22,%22OverrideDocumentCountryCode%22:null,%22forSaleIn%22:%22%22,%22FSIexclCT%22:%22%22%7D&filtersString=%7B%22TypeCode%22:%22FA:N6SQ%22,%22FundName%22:%22JLR%20Bond%22,%22BaseCurrency%22:%22GBX%22,%22PriceType%22:1,%22TimePeriod%22:%22%22,%22StartDate%22:%22Mon%20Mar%2001%202021%22,%22EndDate%22:%22Thu%20Mar%2004%202021%22%7D";
  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  file = DriveApp.getFolderById("my_FolderID").createFile(blob);
}
```

- Before you use this script, please replace `my_FolderID` with your folder ID.